# Swift property wrappers. Assign by reference

Tags: swift, string, reference-type

I would like to share a string between classes, and keep modifications made on that string synchronised.

I thought of doing a property wrapper like:

```
@propertyWrapper class StringHolder {
  var wrappedValue: String?
  init(wrappedValue: String?) {
    self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
  }
}
```

and then use it:

```
@StringHolder var sharedString: String = "testString"

let anotherClass = AnotherClass()
anotherClass.sharedString = sharedString 

anotherClass.sharedString = "modified"

//sharedString is still "testString"
```

The problem is that when assigning the sharedString, only the wrapped value is re-set.
Is it possible to have the same wrapper assigned by reference to two properties?

Comment: No, this will not work this way. Technically, you could put some kind of identifier to your wrapper and share wrapped values with the same identifier (e.g. using a shared dictionary) but still you would have to somehow specify which properties are using the same wrapper and it would just make the feature more unreadable.
In this case the best solution would be a custom class wapper, not a property wrapper. The code will be also much easier to read, trust me.

Comment: If you are looking for reference-type behaviour of a `String`, you could just use `NSString`.

Comment: I ended up with the a normal class wrapping the value, as @Sulthan said. Probably more self-explanatory.  Thanks for the comments.